# Decoding ULEB128

Tags: delphi

**pseudocode:**

```
function DecodeULEB128(var AULEB128: UInt64): UInt64;
var
  lShift : Cardinal;
  lByte : Byte;
begin
  Result := 0;
  lShift = 0;

  while true do
  begin
    lByte := next byte of AULEB128;
    Result = Result or (low order 7 bits of lByte << lShift);
    if (high order bit of lByte = 0) then
       break;
    Inc(lShift, 7);
  end;
end;
```

I have 2 problems:

1) How do I access the Bytes of AULEB128, to assign one of them to lByte?
2) How do I access the low/high order bits of Byte?

I know how to access low/high order Bits by using the defined records in SysUtils:

```
  WordRec = packed record
    case Integer of
      0: (Lo, Hi: Byte);
      1: (Bytes: array [0..1] of Byte);
  end;

  LongRec = packed record
    case Integer of
      0: (Lo, Hi: Word);
      1: (Words: array [0..1] of Word);
      2: (Bytes: array [0..3] of Byte);
  end;

  Int64Rec = packed record
    case Integer of
      0: (Lo, Hi: Cardinal);
      1: (Cardinals: array [0..1] of Cardinal);
      2: (Words: array [0..3] of Word);
      3: (Bytes: array [0..7] of Byte);
  end;
```

I am used to do something like this: Int64Rec(Var).Lo.

Would I have to use the and operator on the byte to access a bit?

Comment: Int64Rec(Var).Bytes[i] for access of the bytes and masking the bits with and operations is fine. You can use SHL or SHR operations as well to shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function DecodeULEB128(AULEB128: UInt64): UInt64;
var
  I, lShift : Integer;
  lByte : Byte;
begin
  Result := 0;
  lShift := 0;
  for I := 0 to 7 do
  // or maybe 'for I := 7 downto 0' instead? 
  // Not sure which direction you should be looping...
  begin
    lByte := Int64Rec(AULEB128).Bytes[I];
    Result := Result or (UInt64(lByte and $7F) shl lShift);
    if (lByte and $80) = 0 then
       Break;
    Inc(lShift, 7);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes looks pretty similar to the one I made based on the comment of LU RD. Thanks anyway for your good solution!